# Using Lists in Python: Accepting Inputs using List Functions

Tags: python, list

I am learning beginner python and recently stumbled across this practice problem regarding lists:

You are the owner of a cheese shop, "The Deceased Macaw" and a
customer has arrived. Write a program to greet them.
You should first ask if the customer is interested in cheddar, if so, then they
are given cheddar. Otherwise, you say that you'll find something.
If they say that they don't want cheese, you ask them why they are in a
cheese shop?
In this exercise, valid user responses are "yes" "Yes" "no" and "No". Any
other response is met with "I don't know what you're talking about." You are
not permitted to use "and" in this assignment. You must use lists.

Obviously this problem would be relatively simple if you were allowed to accept direct inputs, but since the nature of the problem has to do with lists, I have absolutely no idea how to incorporate a list within the question. I have no idea where to start besides making a list that includes the four responses, and pulling responses from the list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    response = ["yes","Yes","no","No"]
    like_cheese = str(input("Do you like cheese? "))
    if like_cheese == response[0] or like_cheese == response[1]:
        cheddar = str(input("Is cheddar ok? "))
        if cheddar == response[0] or cheddar == response[1]:
            print("Very well, here you are.")
        elif cheddar == response[2] or response[3]:
            print("Oh, then I suppose we will locate another reasonably cheesy comestible.")
        else:
            print("I don't know what you're talking about.")
    elif like_cheese == response[2] or like_cheese == repsonse[3]:
        print("Well, I don't know what you're doing in a cheese shop then.")
```

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated, thank you.
Edit: Actually I think this code might work, if there is any way to optimize it or if there is anything I overlooked I would be glad to take any advice.

Comment: Write some code, see if it works at all, post it here. Then people will help you work with that code. If you have no code, this is not the right place to ask questions.

Comment: Yup, I've added some code. I actually think this one works, I just need to test the values real quick. We do not need to account for "bad" responses, so this code may work,

Comment: You can do `if like_cheese in ['yes', 'Yes']`

Comment: `cheddar == response[2] or response[3]` is a classic rookie mistake. This evaluates to `if (cheddar == response[2]) or response[3]`. Since any non-empty string is True and `response[3]` is defined as non-empty, it will always pass.

Comment: As a kick in the right direction, consider `affirmatives = ['yes', 'Yes']; negatives = ['no', 'No']; valid_responses = affirmatives + negatives`

Answer (score 0):

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # divide list, yes/no
    response_yes = ["yes", "Yes"]
    response_no = ["no", "No"]

    like_cheese = str(input("Do you like cheese? "))
    if like_cheese in response_yes:
        cheddar = str(input("Is cheddar ok? "))
        if cheddar in response_yes:
            print("Very well, here you are.")
        elif cheddar in response_no:
            print("Oh, then I suppose we will locate another reasonably cheesy comestible.")
        else:
            print("I don't know what you're talking about.")
    elif like_cheese in response_no:
        print("Well, I don't know what you're doing in a cheese shop then.")
    else:
        # Add: When the first input was unexpected
        print("I don't know what you're talking about.")
```